# Finding the Subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory

H= $\langle (1 2 3 4),(24)\rangle$

In this exercise i am trying to find all 8 element of H.I have spent a long time trying trying to solve this question by applying the formative definition of subgroup generation and trying to extrapolate information from limited worked solutions i find online but i cant quite seem to grasp this topic. What method would one use to solve a question like this?

Comment: What is G? (Perhaps G=H?) And then, I suspect $H<S_4$, am I right?

Comment: Renaming $1,2,3,4$ in $0,1,2,3$ it is the group of affine transformations $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ : $\{ a \mapsto ca+d \bmod 4,  \gcd(c,4) = 1\}$

Comment: @blumer just changed G to H my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes some knowledge of the symmetric group $S_4$. Without some wider knowledge of groups, the only method you can really use is to calculate and see. As Stefan has posted you have $a^4=b^2=1, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$ as a classic presentation of the dihedral group of order $8$ - one thing to look for is what happens when you conjugate elements - because that will sometimes give you things you recognise.

You have an element of order $4$ and an element of order $2$ which does not commute with it, so the order is greater than $4$, and is a multiple of $4$. The generators are both found in the symmetric group $S_4$ of order $24$ so $H$ will be a subgroup of this group. The admissible orders are therefore $8$, $12$ and $24$.

Now note that both the permutations you are given are odd permutations. The only subgroup of $S_4$ of order $12$ is the alternating group $A_4$, which contains only even permutations, so this cannot be $H$.

Note also that if you split the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into the two subsets $\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}$ both of the permutations given either fix the two subsets or exchange them. Since the two permutations generate the group, it cannot contain any permutations which mix these subsets, and in particular it can't be the whole symmetric group. If we think back to the dihedral group for a moment and consider it as the symmetries of a square, this reflects the geometric fact that diagonals are mapped to diagonals - the sets are the vertices at the end of each diagonal. I note in passing that if the transposition had been $(1 2)$ you would have got the whole symmetric group. You would see that most easily by finding an element of order $3$ so the order would be divisible by $12$, but couldn't be the alternating group.

So the group you are looking at will have eight elements. (Half of these eight will be even permutations, which will form a normal subgroup of order $4$ within $H$)

You get four elements as powers of the four-cycle, and four more as their products with the transposition you are given. That makes all eight.

Alternatively you can see the only possibility for a group of even permutations of order four is the four-group within $S_4$, and multiply by one of the odd permutations you have been given to get the four odd permutations in $H$.

If you start multiplying things, you will find all eight elements quite quickly. Most of this explanation is about (a) having a way of knowing that you are finished and (b) knowing which of the different isomorphism classes of groups of order eight you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $$H = \langle (1234), (24) | (1234)^4 = e, (24)^2 = e, (24)(1234)(24) = (1432) \rangle$$

Doesn't this representation remind you of a well-known group?

Comment: Is $D_8$ supposed to be a well-known group for starters ??

Comment: @reuns To be fair $D_8$ isn't that hard of a group for beginners. So it's arguable whether it's well-known or not. Anyway the group representation I gave should help him write the elements

Comment: Personally I needed to understand quotient rings before I could understand quotients of the free group and hence presentations of groups.

Comment: @reuns I agree, but knowing how the elements of $D_8$ conjugate isn't that of an advanced topic, I believe.

Comment: Are these the elements of H? 
\begin{align}
\{e,(1,2,3,4),(1,2)(3,4),(1432),(1,3),(2,4),(1,4)(2,3),(1,2)(3,4)\} 
\end{align}

Comment: @TimJones Yeah you're right